# Confused about my Ubuntu version and having problem with updates

Tags: 16.04, apt, 18.04, package-management, upgrade

I had Ubuntu 14 and upgraded to 16, but there were some problems during the installation with `apt update`, `upgrade`, etc. The computer is working now, but I still have some minor issues, some times depending on what package I try to install.

The thing is, I am supposedly using Ubuntu 16.04 now (that's what "about this computer" says) but if I enter `tty1`, for example, I get this:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS ......
(login)
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS ....
Documentation
..
0 packages can be updated
...
...
New release '18.04.2 LTS' available.
Run do-release-upgrade to upgrade it
```

Which is very confusing. Regarding some problems I have, for example, I get this error when trying to execute an application:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

So I use `apt-file search` and find that I need `libmysqlclient-dev`, but this is what I get when I try to install the package:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Anything I could try to fix these problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Would it be difficult for you to just do a clean install to delete what you have and start over with a clean updated version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)